# Java - Ways to compose XSL-FO

Tags: java, pdf, xsl-fo

I want to use XSL-FO to write PDFs. But everywhere I look, there is no really integration between Java and the composition of such documents, in a way like add/edit objects(like tables, images, etc…) to a document and then ask to generate the corresponding XML. Is there any advancement in this area that I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is an example of how to generate PDF files with Apache FOP using Java: [Integrating Apache FOP with Java project](http://blog.e-zest.com/integrating-apache-fop-with-java-project-to-generate-pdf-files/)

Answer (score 2):

Did you look at Apache FOP?
http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/

Even the PDFs at their site are created using their own framework.

Comment: As far as I know, the Apache FOP is meant only for compilation of the XML files, not the document composition itself.

Comment: But Java can be used to produce the XML, which needn't necessarily be in a file.

Comment: The document composition (XML) can be easily done with JAXB or any other API.